# Different scales of vector layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I have a problem with overlaying two different scales vector files such as 1:10000 and 1:50000 in Arc Gis format .There is a shift with these two layers .When I overlay with these vector files in to rectified google images this shift can be seen clearly..If somebody can help me pls notice the method to adjust this shift .

Comment: Are all your layers in the same CRS?

Comment: is the shift always in the same direction ?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot to clarify your problem?

Comment: Is this because the layers were digitized at different scales, and thus show finer or coarser detail and so don't match each other? Or do they match each other, but not google?

Answer (score 1):

The shift is likely in the Google Earth / or the source imagery itself.  In one of my areas of interest the imagery is off by roughly 30m. This is not uncommon. You should not use Google Earth imagery for QAQC and analysis. Also, imagery in Google Earth that is outside of popular urban areas is likely to be outdated, in many cases 10 years or older which may present other problems.  You can contact Digital Globe or similar or a licensed distributor and order ortho-rectified imagery from the source.